# Chrome Extension And Dom Capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension for one of my pages. I'm getting the data in a dom element on the page and querying the api and calling it back. On the site where I get data, the page does not reload when switching between pages. So I can't catch Dom loading or locationchange in foreground.js because the page is not refreshed and i solve my problem by timeout.The dom in foreground.js is only triggered when the page is refreshed. The codes I wrote in settimeout are triggered when switching between pages. How can i solve this problem without timeout?

background.js CODES

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo,tab) => {
                if(changeInfo.status == "complete" && tab.status == "complete") {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: {tabId: tabId},
                    files: ["./foreground.js"]
                })
            }
});
```

foreground.js CODES

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { alert('Dom'); }); //not working

window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
  console.log('location changed!');
}) //not working

setTimeout(() => {
let find = document.querySelector(".contentsdetailscontainer").textContent;
},1000); //this is working
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: how can i solve this problem without timeout?

Comment: But what problem? You're showing "working" code that has nothing to do with the "not working" code, they are completely unrelated function calls, on different objects. So what exactly are you asking about here? And how would you know that the "working" code works? It assigns a locally scoped variable, does nothing with it, and then that variable gets cleaned up again. There is nothing in that code that demonstrate it even runs.

Comment: My problem is that I can't catch the dom load outside of the settimeout before the page is refreshed. I want to capture the dom load so that I can get the data inside an element on the page. otherwise the element is null.

Answer (score 1):

foreground.js executed when [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `complete`, which means `DOMContentLoaded` has already been fired.

If at that point the needed element is not present in the DOM, you can use the [`Mutation Observer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and wait for it.

Here is a simple example (very inefficient because it observes entire body, if only a specific element changes, you should observe it instead, so use it only as a guide):

```
var nodeFound = false;
const observer = new MutationObserver(() =>
{
  const node = document.querySelector(".contentsdetailscontainer");
  if (node && node.textContent)
  {
    if (!nodeFound)
    {
      //only show alert once per new page.
      alert("node found");
      nodeFound = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    nodeFound = false; //reset in case page updated again
  }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

Comment: I just learned about MutationObserver, it is a very nice feature, but unfortunately this is not the solution to my problem. My problem is that I cannot catch the dom load before the page is refreshed. I want to capture the dom load so that I can get the data inside an element on the page. otherwise the element is null.

Comment: foreground.js executed when [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)  is `complete`, which means `DOMContentLoaded` has already been fired. if at that point the needed element is not present, you can use the MutationObserver to wait for it to be inserted into the DOM.